# Speaking truth or doing good? What is the more important in Islam?

Tags: practical-islam

I remember, I read that once a person came to Muslims in either Macca or Madina and they had to make arrangements for his stay so they decided to give the honor to one of the men. When they both went home and there was very less food at his home which could only be sufficient for one person, he did a trick that he sat with the guest and started to eat and then closed the light and pretended that there was something wrong with the light. He stopped eating in real after that but acted if he was eating with the other guy.

Next day, the Holy Prophet told him that God has liked his hospitality.
**There might be a lot of citations needed in the above as I wrote it from my memory and did not copied it. Please improve the above mentioned story if you find the exact one.**

Now my question is that what is that our religion teaches? Doing good with the people or always speaking truth? I know speaking truth is a good thing but in cases where you are getting more good benefit for other people and for humanity, can a person lie too?

I understand that the person could have said to the guest that sorry we do not have enough food. But he did not eat it himself nor his wife but did a very good hospitality with a trick.

Please help me understand the moral of the story. Thanks

Comment: As you said it was a trick, no lie as nothing wrong they told, this is called **Turiyeh** and is allowed in Islam (_there are many examples of that stated in Quran, see [here](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2468/is-concept-called-taqiyya-in-islam-for-propagation-of-islam-around-the-world/2937#2937)_). Also the story you told is about Imam Ali and fatimah --peace be upon them--, as believed by Shia muslims.

Comment: Thanks. If people can improve the question I would be thankful.

Answer (score 4):

The hadith you mentioned sounds like [this hadith](http://sunnah.com/urn/355160).  Furthermore being hospitable to ones guest is very important and is of good character.  The Prophet (peace and blessings be upon him) said:

> مَنْ كَانَ يُؤْمِنُ بِاللَّهِ وَالْيَوْمِ الآخِرِ فَلْيُكْرِمْ
> ضَيْفَهُ
>
> Whoever believes in Allah and the Last Day, should serve his guest
> generously
>
> [Saheeh Bukari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:6135)

Furthermore lying is a sin, and those who lie will end up in hell.

> إِنَّ الْكَذِبَ يَهْدِي إِلَى الْفُجُورِ وَإِنَّ الْفُجُورَ يَهْدِي
> إِلَى النَّارِ وَإِنَّ الرَّجُلَ لَيَكْذِبُ حَتَّى يُكْتَبَ كَذَّابًا
>
> and lying leads to obscenity and obscenity leads to Hell, and the
> person tells a lie until he is recorded as a liar
>
> [Saheeh Muslim](http://sunnah.com/urn/263070)

***But*** it is ok to lie only in [three cases](http://sunnah.com/urn/672410):

1. To please ones wife
2. To lie in War is ok
3. to lie to bring peace between people

Comment: I like how you give your answers from Qur'aan and Hadeeth, shukran brother!
Allah make us not of the liars, and give us good judgement regarding how we use our words. ameen

Answer (score -2):

According to the hadith from Ebu’d-Derda:

Sometimes, believers can steal; sometimes, believers can fornicate. But they never lie!

But i didn't see anywhere which means "believers are doing always good".

This hadith explains your question preciesly.

Comment: Hello ans welcome to [islam.se]. Could you provide a more precise reference to the hadith you are referring to?